# FULL OUTER JOIN or UNION?

Tags: sql, db2

confused how to achieve this maybe with FULL OUTER or a UNION. I want to join results in such a way that

```
Table1                     Table2
---------------           ----------------- 
ID  Name Salary           ID    Fruits
---------------           ----------------- 
1   John   1000           1     Apples 
1   Henry  4000           1     Mangoes 
1   Smith  1000           1     Tomatoes
```

Result should be

```
ResultTable
       ------------------------
       ID Name  Salary  Fruits
       -----------------------   
       1  John  1000    Apples
       1  John  1000    Mangoes
       1  John  1000    Tomatoes
       1  Henry 4000    Apples
       1  Henry 4000    Mangoes
       1  Henry 4000    Tomatoes
       1  Smith 1000    Apples
       1  Smith 1000    Mangoes
       1  Smith 1000    Tomatoes
```

Comment: you IDs are obviously wrong .. right ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a cartesian product join or Cross Join ..

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  table1, table2
```

or

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

(reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/sqlp/rbafymstcrojo.htm)

Comment: +1 Did you edit your answer after you saw mine or did we just write the almost exact same thing at the same time?

Comment: @Mark, lol .. i googled for a db2 specific answer and the link i found quote the same text and got it from there.. *hehe*

Comment: Ok no worries... I also googled DB2 but after I wrote my answer... I think your answer is better so I will delete mine.

Comment: @Mark, me too .. i searched after my initial answer, and edited after if found the link.. you should not delete though.. *Stack Overflow* in answers as well :)

Comment: Thank you Gaby. Hey fellows I am sorry I just can mark 1 answer so I mark the first one. I give you points though. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

use `cross join` if db2 has it

Answer (score 2):

You might want to rethink your DB naming standards - naming columns as "ID" but then allowing duplicates isn't a great idea IMHO.

Because of the duplication, it isn't quite clear what is needed, but assuming that ID is a red herring, I think a CROSS JOIN is the correct approach in your scenario

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Salary, t2.Fruit 
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```

OR

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Salary, t2.Fruit 
from Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

Comment: yeah I know about the duplication, its just the situation in original tables is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, if you want all the rows in Table1 for all the rows in Table2, then a cross join (ie. a cartesian join) is the answer.

On the other hand, in the scenario above, an inner join on ID would also return the same resultset:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Salary, t2.Fruit 
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Then again, if this query relates to the same problem as some of your Crystal questions, you might find this resultset more useful:

ResultTable

```
   ------------------------
   ID Name  Salary  Fruits
   -----------------------   
   1  John  1000    
   1  Henry 4000    
   1  Smith 1000    
   1                Apples
   1                Mangoes
   1                Tomatoes
```

which can be obtained with this query:

```
select ID, Name, Salary, '' Fruit from Table1 union all
select ID, '' Name, NULL Salary, Fruit from Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Salary, T2.Fruit 
  FROM Table1 AS T1
       CROSS JOIN Table2 AS T2;
```

Avoid using infixed notation:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Salary, T2.Fruit 
  FROM Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2;
```

I'm not quite sure why but folk definitely don't like the infixed notation, especially when you add a `WHERE` clause. They will tell you that `CROSS JOIN` is SQL-92, which is indeed correct but then infixed notation is SQL-92 as well.

Oh, and some folk call the infixed notation without a `WHERE` clause a Cartesian Product, which is indeed correct but then a `CROSS JOIN` is a Cartesian Product as well.

Comment: Heya, thanks for the comment onedaywhen. What do you mean by infix notation ? And how is it different from a cross join ?

Comment: @Popo: infix notation is the term given to the construct where the table expressions are comma-separated without explicit `JOIN` conditions e.g. `FROM Table1, Table2;` A cross join is different because the table expressions are not comma-separated and have `CROSS JOIN` conditions e.g. `FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2;`

Comment: An example of infix notation is `SELECT * T1 CROSS JOIN T2` -- I have this entirely reversed in this answer and comment. What was I thinking?!